# Creating a new array of data from existing one

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array like this.

```
[{
    "image": "image1.png",
    "url": "link1"
},{
    "image": "image2.png",
    "url": "link2"
},{
    "image": "image3.png",
    "url": "link3"
}]
```

How can I create a new array like this from the above one

```
["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"]
```

This is my code  and json encoded `$main` is added on the top

```
foreach ($main as $key =>$value){
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
         if($key1==='image'&&$key1!=url){
            $image=$value1; 
            $array12 = array( 'image' =>$image);    
        }
        }
        $array12=json_encode($array12);
        print_r($array12);
  }
```

The result I am getting is

```
{"image":"image1.png"}{"image":"image2.png"}{"image":"image3.png"}
```

Comment: Should be something like `array_column($main, 'image');`

Comment: just like this ex : array_column(json_decode($your_json), 'your_column')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this like this:

```
$array12 = [];

foreach ($main as $key =>$value){
    $image=$value["image"]; 
    array_push($array12, $image);    
}

$array12=json_encode($array12);
print_r($array12);
```